# mysql order rows by a record with two different values

Tags: mysql

i have records that have value equal to 1 or 2 i want to order rows by this record like this

```
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
```

how can i do this order by only orders by DESC or ASC ?

note :  there is a primary key id, and there is a created date

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `phone_number` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `first_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `last_name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `sex` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL, << this will have only 1 or 2
    `created_date` DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    `account_status` TINYINT(1) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`uid`)
);
```

Comment: @iMyth and value  ? ? you want ASC/DESC by which column  ?

Comment: `sex` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL, << this will have only 1 or 2

Comment: i want the order like i mentioned in the question

Comment: You mean even in Database they have first 5 records with 1 and another 5 records with 2, you want it as  1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2.. right ?

Comment: yes , but not first 5 records the sex value will be randomly 1 or 2 nothing else and i need to select them  like this 1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2

Comment: Is there any relationship between the 1s and 2s? which would allow you to group in such a way (for example last_name, phone_number)?

Comment: look what i'm trying do that ,, when i want to display users i will select the latest registered user "order by `created_date` DESC " but this sometime show all male users and sometimes not what i'm trying to do is show newest users with equals values from males and females

Comment: So most recent 1 (or 2) as row1 followed by most recent 2 (or 1) prior to row1 as row2 followed by the most recent  1 (or 2) prior to row2 and so on? Seems like you would throw away a lot of recently created users.

Comment: Edit the data set and the desired result. I suspect that (at most) only 3 columns are relevant to this problem, so I would remove the others for the purpose of a clear and concise question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (
  SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN  uid, first_name , 
    @y:=IF(@sex=sex,@y+1,1) AS rnk, @sex:=sex AS sex
  FROM (SELECT @sex:=NULL) AS x
  JOIN users
  ORDER BY sex, uid DESC
) AS t
ORDER BY rnk ASC, sex ASC;
```

Comment: you're too close but this result in this > https://i.imgur.com/ra7m6PK.png

Comment: Kind of goes against your original comment.

Comment: And why do you think the optimizer would get this wrong? Oh, and y never gets initialised ?!?